# Triggers and order of execution on two different objects

Tags: apex, triggercontext, trigger

Hi I'm trying to totally wrap my head around how one trigger's execution could affect another. To make things clearer here's a scenario. Say I have 2 objects A and B. Both objects have a trigger each that fires after update. Object A makes an update on object B. By the order of execution as seen [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm/%22here%22), number 6 (Executes all after triggers) and number 17(Commits all DML operations to the database) at what point during Object A trigger execution does the Object B trigger fire? Is it at number 6 or after the commit of all DML operations to DB at number 17?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Triggers only fire on DML operations which you have already pointed out, does not occur until step 17 in the order of execution seen below and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

So in your scenario, The trigger for Object B will not fire until step 17 (the DML operation is committed) in the trigger for Object A.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick answer and explanation. It does makes sense to me.